# Change colors of background

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div called main:

```
 <div id="main">
```

I also have a div with colors:

```
 <div id="colors">
```

In the div colors i have a list of colors: example

red

blue

yellow

If I click on 1 color I want to change the color of the div main.

I already have:

```
$("#main").hover(function() 
{ 
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800); 
}
    ,function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#8D8D86" }, 800); 
});
```

Which changes the color like I want.

But i want this effect for the colors in the div.

So if I click yellow the color must be not  #a7bf51   but if I click yellow it must be yellow, if i click red it must be red.

i also tried

```
 <a  href="#top" class="testClick" onclick="
                document.getElementById('#bord').style.backgroundColor='#350000';
            ">Rood </a>
```

which turns the background image to #350000

but I want to have a big list with a lot of colors 20+ so it would be better if i can make a function, and with the function i also have an effect with animate which is nice.

So can someone help me in the right way of changing the background colors with the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="colors"> 
  <span id="#a7bf51">red</span>
  <span id="#8D8D86">green</span>
  ........
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#colors span').click(function(){
     var color=$(this).attr('id');
     $('#main').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: color }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Thanx this is the best answer for me ! now i can change color names and add a diffrent shade of color example if i use red i can use  #730000 insted of the normal color thanx for the help

Comment: sure... your you can use data attribute `data-color` incase of id.. if incase the ids ends up beign same. anyways this should work...welcome.. happy coding.. :)..gad it helped

Answer (score 1):

```
var color = '';
$('div').click(function() {
    var clr = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    var color= hexc(clr);


$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: color }, 'fast');

})
```

hope it works..

Comment: i'm not sure how to add this.  i have added it to $(document).ready(function(){   and changed  $('div').click(function()   to   $('div').click(function()   $('#colors').click(function()   where #colors is the div with a list of colors like in the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#colors p').click(function(){

    color = $(this).innerHTML;

    $('#bord').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: color
    }, 800);

}
```

This is assuming that your 'colors' div is full of p elements which contain the colors

It also assumes that your text colors are valid HTML color names.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#svg-color

Comment: w3c is official web standard, and therefore more reliable. It's also more relevant.

Off topic: [Tim Berners-Lee](http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/) went to my primary school :D

Comment: However despite repeated attempts from W3Org to get w3schools  to change their completely unrelated name and repeated attempts from the more advanced coder community to get them to clean up their erroneous ways, w3schools still suck. If you want the w3org ones, MDN had a [link to them](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#svg-color)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    Some content
</div>

<div id="colors">
   <p>Red</p>
   <p>Blue</p>
   <p>Yellow</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#colors p').on('click',function(){
            var color = $(this).text();
            $('#main').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: color }, 800);
        });
    });
```